# Scalaz: how do I use `traverseS` on regular scala List?

Tags: scala, scalaz

If I have a plain scala `List[A]` (i.e. `scala.collection.immutable.List`) and I have some state monad `State[S,B]`. I'd like to use Scalaz's specialized `traverseS` ala:

```
val stuff: scala.collection.immutable.List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
val state: State[S,A]
stuff.traverseS(i => modify { ... })
```

What do I need to import to convert `scala.collection.immutable.List` to Scalaz's `List`? I couldn't find searching through GitHub and I wasn't able to get it working with trying to import carte blanche. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you tell us what the actual error you are getting is?

Comment: @stew it couldn't find an a witness to the implementation of `Traverse[List]`. So, I think your solution of importing the typeclass instances should fix this. I thought that happened automatically when doing `import scalaz.std._` but I guess not. Thanks for the quick response. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: ah, no if you want all instances the import would be `import scalaz.std.AllInstances._`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

scalaz doens't have its own list implementation.  Likely you just need to import the list typeclass instances with `import scalaz.std.list._` and the traverse syntax with `import scalaz.syntax.traverse._`

Comment: And also `scalaz.syntax.traverse._` I'd imagine

Comment: Thanks @stew. I'll check tonight when I get home and hopefully that will work!